# How to calculate power supply output current from its three phase input current

Tags: power-supply, current-measurement, three-phase

In my lab I have three-phase electric power according to the following diagram:

[image]

I'm using a three-phase power supply TRIO-PS-2G/3AC/24DC/40 which delivers 24V and max current 40A. Using a Current Clamp I measured the input current on each phase to be 0.6A.
My question is, how to calculate the output current according to this three-phase input current.
From its manual the power supply efficiency is typ. 93 % (400 V AC).

Comment: Are the loads connected in star or delta?

Comment: The load is the three phase power supply, don't know how its connected inside. I just want to know the current going out from the 24V output.

Comment: Seems like walking across the bridge to fetch water, but you may have your reasons. I do however need to ask, why not measure the 24 V DC current directly with a clamp?

Comment: Its a 40A power supply, I don't have a 40A max current multi-meter. For now the current consumption is low but it can be much higher, I need a simple strategy to evaluate the 24V output current from its input three-phase AC current.

Comment: This is an XY Question -- your real question is "How do I measure 40A with a meter that doesn't have that range?"  **If** the power factor of the power supply were 1, **if** the efficiency was *exactly* what the label said (and I could use up a comment explaining why it's not), **if** the incoming voltage were exactly as specified, and **if** the output were exactly 24V, then you could compute the supply's input power, divide by 24V, divide by the efficiency, and have the output current.  There's too many "ifs" for that to work.

Comment: Your real answer is to either buy a meter that measures 40A, or grab a meter that reliably measures 0-50mV and buy or build a current shunt, or read the data sheet for your power supply and see if it has a built-in current shunt and a way for a user to tap into that.

Comment: Wanted to avoid the hassle of removing those thick wires and put a power resistor in series etc... No problem of having a couple of amps error, just want to make sure we really need those 40A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the input power you need the power factor from the [data sheet](https://www.phoenixcontact.com/online/portal/gb?uri=pxc-oc-itemdetail:pid=2903156&library=gben&tab=1) which is 0.77.

\$
Input\,Power = 3 \times 230\;V \times 0.6\;A \times 0.77 
= \sqrt 3 \times 400\;V \times 0.6\;A \times 0.77 = 320\;W 
\\[2ex]
Output\,Power = Input\,Power \times Efficiency = 320\;W \times 0.93 = 297.6\;W 
\\[2ex]
Output\,Current = \frac{Output\,Power}{Output\,Voltage} = \frac{297.6\;W}{24\;V} = 12.4\; A
\$

But I wouldn't calculate the DC current this way. The power factor and efficiency will change with output load so this calculation can only give a rough guide. Your supply voltage is also likely to vary somewhat.

You would be much better off getting a [Hall effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hall_effect) AC/DC clamp meter which will let you read the DC current directly with more accuracy. Clamp meters tend to have high current ranges so will read 40 A directly. Make sure you get one that is DC. Many clamp meters are transformer-operated rather than using a Hall effect sensor and are therefore AC only.

As a bonus you won't need to cut the DC power leads to insert the ammeter in circuit. If you have multiple leads running from the power supply you just need to put all the positive leads (usually) or all the negative leads through the jaws of the ammeter (but not both sets of leads which should give a zero reading). Check the jaws are large enough to accept all the wires you are using.

It is also much safer to be making measurements on a 24 V circuit than on a 400 V three-phase circuit which typically have very high fault current levels if you make a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You are measuring the line-currents. Assuming your measurements are right and you have a balanced load. The total current can be simply calculated using Itot = 3 * Iline = 3 * 0.6 = 1.8A

Comment: These are the input currents, I want to know what is the actual output current from the 24V output.